# Windows 2016 Preview 5 as an iSCSI target for TinyPXE iSCSI+iPXE diskless boot

Tags: boot, iscsi, pxe-boot

I'm testing Windows 2016 Preview 5 as an iSCSI target
and using TinyPXE as a DHCP+iPXE server for diskless boot...

Access to Windows 2016 iSCSI target
Works OK from a iSCSI initiator like Windows 7 or Windows 10...

I'm trying to boot from a iSCSI target using TinyPXE/iPXE as DHCP/TFTP server

The PXE client finds the DHCP server...
loads the undionly.kpxe...
starts looking for the iSCSI target and fails with the message "Could not open SAN device..."

*CONFIGURATION*
Option67=undionly.kpxe
Option17=iscsi:10.0.0.213:tcp:3260:0:vm2016-demo1-target
ExtraOption=iscsi:10.0.0.213:tcp:3260:0:vm2016-demo1-target
Option3=

Below are the Server/Target configuration and the TinyPXE screenshots...
Any ideas are welcome...

[image: iSCSI target t1]

[image: Boot screen from diskless station and TinyPXE screenshot]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to unreleased software.

Comment: Sorry mate... there a lot of us using preview releases... and this is a BIG and important one... anyway just wait 2 weeks and you'll have the released version...

I also tested the same in windows 2012... the result is the same... 
So... if it makes you happy,,, I'll edit this to refer to Windows 2012...

Comment: Me too, I'm trying it, but we make it very clear that serverfault is for production, supported systems.

Comment: @Chopper3 [This older question](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3611/37681) you asked on Meta seems to have more supporters that say the topic of a preview release alone is not sufficient reason to close questions as a matter of policy...

Answer (score 1):

Your error is described on iPXE's website [here](http://ipxe.org/err/2c0d60).

It seems to be related to the default (you do not define one) UUID based IQN not being accepted by you target.

Try running a Wireshark traffic capture from your iSCSI target PC and see what's really going on.

Comment: The iPXE initiator IQN is the 2nd in the server screenshot...
I'll try some tcp captures to further analyze the problem...

Comment: I know, and it is the default created by iPXE for your client but for some reason your target is not taking it. The Wireshark capture will help you to see if it is really used by the client, if it is refused by the target, or what. Also try to see what `"extra-option` really means; that TinyPXE interface is really cumbersome...